# Strange behavior with routing and hypertext

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning webdevelopment. For now the root address of my website is extended like www.mywebsite.com/project2/project2/public.
There is a hypenrlink from one page to a route:

```
<a href="/movetocomplete/{{$object->id}}">{{$object->name}}</a>
```

If the href is left as above, there is a 404 error saying that there is nothing at

> www.mywebsite.com/movetocomplete/id#.

But if the href is

> project2/project2/public/movetocomplete/{{$object->id}},

there is a 404 error saying there is nothing at

> www.mywebsite.com/project2/project2/public/project2/project2/publicmovetocomplete/id#.

The route is

> Route::get('/movetocomplete/{object}', 'UserController@movetocomplete');

Answer (score 0):

I think your Route for this link should not begin with a slash.

The correct route for this url

```
Route::get('movetocomplete/{object}', 'UserController@movetocomplete');
```

And only the welcome root page needs a slash, just one slash.

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

This is the minimum configuration for Nginx location block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;

    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: If the slash is left in front of the hyperlink path, and is removed from the route, there is an 404 error. If the slash is removed from both, the address is /project2/project2/public//movetocomplete/id#

Comment: Which Web server do you use? Apache or Nginx? I think there are some configuration you are missing. For this situation, it is not all to do with App Route.

Comment: I don't know. Its hosted by godaddy.

Comment: Any advice on fixing the configuration? I'm still having related problems.

Comment: If your web server is Apache. There is almost nothing to configure. But when it comes to Nginx. You need to do some configuration on Nginx if you could do it on godaddy. This is for minimum configuration on nginx: